# Chrome input error message not positioned properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On input error messages notification in Chrome looks pushed down like it has margin-top set, any idea how to fix this?

This should be on first input field
http://image.prntscr.com/image/fe5cba38758c41a4acb85e86c88c3953.jpeg

In Firefox it is OK.

I am using Bootstrap, markup is this

```
<form role="form">

    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <label for="name" class="sr-only">Your name</label>
        <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="inputName" placeholder="Name">
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
     <label for="email" class="sr-only">Your email</label>
        <input required type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your email"
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <label for="subject" class="sr-only">Subject</label>
     <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Have you added `body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }` in your code?

Comment: http://www.codeply.com/go/Hw1buKqNLY

Comment: @Nashcheez I have put it now but it is still the same. Also in IE11 it works OK

Comment: @IvanTopić Do you think you can share more code (including the css) so that I could look further?